# Moving 3D camera up and down around a central point in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 3d, webgl, three.js

i am making a very basic application in ThreeJs, i have an object in the center and 2 sliders (horizontal rotation and vertical rotation). Both sliders output an integer between 0 and 360. So far i managed to move my camera around the object horizontally with the first slider. But i want to be able to move the camera up and down around the object with the second slider, and i cannot figure out the correct math.

Here is what my equations look like at the moment:

```
camera.position.x =  originX + radius * Math.cos(horizontal_degrees*(Math.PI/180));
camera.position.z =  originY + radius *Math.sin(controls.horizontal_rotation(Math.PI/180));
camera.position.y=  //??? i can't figure this out.
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code of [this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama_fisheye.html) as base:

```
var horizontal_degrees = 0;
var vertical_degrees = 0;

var theta = horizontal_degrees * Math.PI / 180;
var phi = vertical_degrees * Math.PI / 180;

camera.position.x = originX + radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
camera.position.y = originY + radius * Math.cos( phi );
camera.position.z = originZ + radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does the "lat" variable refer to? the Latitude? Thank you.